# How to make a batch file wait for fractions of a second?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

I want to make a batch file wait for 0.5 or 0.25 seconds.
I have already tried `timeout /t 0.5` but it is not working.

It is something like:
`@echo off color a cls :top echo %random% timeout /t 0.5 echo %random% goto top`

Edit : Thanks for the answers y'all

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this: `ping 127.0.0.1 -n 1 -w 500> nul` 500 is the time in ms.

EDIT:

As rojo posted in the comments this won't work as expected for 250ms:

> ping used this way pauses a minimum of 500ms. Using any value lower than 500 still results in a half second pause

Comment: To clarify here: The address to be pinged must not reply, otherwise the `-w` parameter does not apply.

Comment: `ping` used this way pauses a minimum of 500ms.  Using any value lower than 500 still results in a half second pause.

Comment: You can't do it with `timeout`. That's why I told you to use ping instead ;-)

Comment: Amazing hack man!

Comment: This doesn't correctly answer the original question, which asks to make a batch file wait for 0.5 or 0.25 seconds. As stated, any value lower than 500ms still results in a 500ms pause, and yet a misleading 250ms is used. The answer is noteworthy at best.

Comment: Why was this downvoted is beyond me. Thanks a lot!!! It's an awesome hack

Comment: @Gaspa79 The downvote is correct. 250 is a valid parameter but it won't work as expected. The lower bound for the ping delay is 500ms so even if you pass 250 as a parameter it will still be interpreted as 500.

Comment: Please use 192.0.2.0. This is a test ip range. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses, this method will fail if 1.1.1.1 exists (which is now a dns ip that cloudflare owns)

Comment: @WHol thx, I've updated the answer.

Comment: 500 isn't just the lower bound, it is the timing resolution. 1499 will round down to 1000 and 1999 will round down to 1500. It's always in multiples of 500 milliseconds.

Comment: Pinging `127.0.0.1` will not work as it will answer immediately.

Answer (score 10):

`TIMEOUT` only works in increments of whole seconds.

There are other third-party "sleep" executables you can download.

Alternatively, you could use the `Sleep` method in VBScript. It accepts values as milliseconds. Here is a simple example (save it to `SLEEP.VBS` or whatever name you want):

```
ms = WScript.Arguments(0)
WScript.Sleep ms
```

Then, in your batch file call it like this for a 0.5 second delay:

```
CSCRIPT SLEEP.VBS 500
```

Answer (score 5):

[See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28369536/) for some worthwhile information.  To summarize, using `ping` to pause is limited to 500ms or greater.  You won't be able to pause for 250ms.  The best solution is to use Windows Scripting Host -- VB Script or JScript.

You can do this with a [batch / JScript hybrid](https://gist.github.com/davidruhmann/5199433) to avoid having to call an external VBS script.  Save this example with a .bat extension and try it.

```js
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off
setlocal

for /L %%I in (10,-1,1) do (
    set /P "=%%I... "<NUL
    call :pause 250
)

echo Done.
goto :EOF

:pause <ms>
cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0" "%~1"
goto :EOF

@end // end batch / begin JScript hybrid code
WSH.Sleep(WSH.Arguments(0));
```

Comment: That's handy.  You made my fast and ugly reset/wakeup batch file with GPIO utility pin toggles run 4x faster now. It would probably work fine @ 100ms too.

Comment: @Barleyman Thanks!  I'm useful sometimes, even if by accident.  :)