# Batch: Slowing processing speed

Tags: performance, batch-file, reducing

I am creating a little project to impress my friends, and was curious on how I could slow down the text outflow on the program, using just one line.

I am having a problem (And trust me, I did my research), and was curious as to how to slow down the batch processing speed in general, without doing `echo hi TIMEOUT 5>nul echo hi again`, etc. But instead, only a single line at the beginning, which slows the output of the text for the whole batch script. Thanks!

Comment: There is no such functionality available. There is no way to set the execution speed of the batch file at the beginning.

Comment: Ken White is right. But see [How to read and print contents of text file line by line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51576615/) The answers show how to output a text file line by line with a customizable wait time between every line printing.

Comment: Do you just want to join multiple lines into one? You can use an ampersand to concatenate them, i.e. `@Echo hi& Timeout 5 /NoBreak>Nul & Echo hi`.

Comment: So you want to create like a Typewriter output. We have some code to do that on DosTips.com. I will see if I can find the forum thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only real way to do this in the batch language would be to use the `call` command to call a function and to work. This can be placed at the bottom of your batch document.

Furthermore, Since your not real clear on your goal here & from reading the comments, I'm going to assume that from `echo hi & TIMEOUT 5>nul echo hi again` you want to display each line after 5 seconds *BUT* from just one line or command. This can be done easily with `call` & an `FOR` loop. In this case we can use `%*` to gather all `"Words Line One"`, `"Words Line Two"` that you wish.

Combining this with simple [syntax-replacement](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) to remove the quotes and we good.

**DelayedLine.bat**

```
@echo off
@setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

Rem | To use the command, Call :SlowOutput "Desired Line" "Desired Line" "Desired Line"

Call :SlowOutput "Line Number One" "Line Number Two" "Line Number Three"

pause>nul
Goto :EOF

:SlowOutput
for %%A in (%*) do (

    Set "String=%%A"
    Set String=!String:"=%!

    echo !String!

    Rem | Change 5 To How Many (Seconds) You Wish
    Timeout 5 /NoBreak>Nul
)
goto :EOF
```

If your goal was to have a typewrighter effect, we can use a script by [hackoo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080770/hackoo) on this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36448240/8667430) and modify it to work with the `call` in an organized matter.

This script will display letter by letter and for each `call "Word" "Word"` new quote a new line. All working by one line via `call`

**LetterDelay.bat**

```
@echo off

Rem | To use the command, Call :SlowText "Desired Text"
Rem | To combine two "echo's" on one line we can use the "&"

Call :SlowText "Hello!" & Call :SlowText "How is your day today?"

pause>nul
Goto :EOF

:SlowText
(
echo strText=wscript.arguments(0^)
echo intTextLen = Len(strText^)

echo intPause = 100
echo For x = 1 to intTextLen
echo     strTempText = Mid(strText,x,1^)
echo     WScript.StdOut.Write strTempText
echo     WScript.Sleep intPause
echo Next

)>%tmp%\%~n0.vbs
@cScript.EXE /noLogo "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs" "%~1"

Rem | echo. is optional. It's used as a constant for a newline \n
echo.
goto :EOF
```

---

For help on any of the commands do the following:

- `call /?`
- `set /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `find /?`
- So on.